# Cannot push an element in attribute of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm building a stack but I don't know why when try to push I get: "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

```
function stack(n) {
  return {
    size: n,
    elements: [],
    push: (item) => {
      if ( this.elements.length < this.size) {
        this.elements.push(item);
        return this.elements;
      } else {
        return this.elements.length !== n ? true : 'Stack Overflow';
      }
    },
    pop: () => {
      if (n !== 0) {
        return n !== 0 ? this.elements.pop() : 'Stack Underflow';
      }
    },
    isEmpty: () => {
      return this.elements === undefined;
    },
    isFull: () => {
      return elements.length === n ? true : false;
    },
  };
};
```

What is happening? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `if (this.elements === undefined ... this.elements.push(1)` - sure? ;)

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do here. wait for my answer.

Comment: Sorry, i want to add the item.

Answer (score 0):

In your code below, if this.elements === undefined, you then try this.elements.push(1). this.elements will need to be instantiated before you use .push().

```
if (this.elements === undefined || this.elements.length < this.size) {
    this.elements.push(1);
    return this.elements;
```

I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but you need to do something like this

```
if (this.elements === undefined || this.elements.length < this.size) {
    this.elements = <instantiate it here>;
    this.elements.push(1);
    return this.elements;
```

Comment: The problem is that I have initialized elements above but i get undefined

Comment: I think the answer above by Faiz99 is the right way to go. Make sure your old javascript isn't cached. Use debugger inside the push function and see what elements and this.elements is defined as within the push function

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit and it works fine. Basically it inits a stack with size n, n = number. Then it performs the methods relative to the size n.

```
 function stack(n) {
  return {
    size: n,
    elements: [],
    push: function(item){
      if (this.elements.length < this.size) {
        this.elements.push(1);
        return this.elements;
      } else {
        return 'Stack Overflow';
      }
    },
    pop: function(){
        return (this.size !== 0 && this.elements.length) ? this.elements.pop() : 'Stack Underflow';
    },
    isEmpty: function(){
      return (this.elements.length < this.size) ? true : false;
    },
    isFull: function(){
      return (this.elements.length == this.size) ? true : false;
    },
  };
};
```

initialize your stack here with a size.

```
var init = stack(2);
```

now call the methods to see whats it doing.

```
    init.pop()
   "Stack Underflow"

    init.isEmpty()
    true

    init.isFull();
    false

    init.push(33)
    [1]

    init.push(67)
    [1, 1]

    init.push(3432)
    "Stack Overflow"
```

Comment: I get a "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" but elements is initialized.